# Bootstrap progress bar with angular 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, progress-bar

I am new to angular and i am unable to understand how to use bootstrap progress bar with Angular.

Below is the bootstrap documentation

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    60%
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the above result using angular. The width % is stored in a variable {{capacity.available}}

So i am doing the following but its not giving me the expected result.

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{capacity.available}}">
        60%
      </div>
    </div>
```

Warning message in the console looks like 
**sanitizing unsafe style value width:54**

What am i doing wrong? Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: What type is stored in capacity.available? Is it string "60%" or number: 60?

Comment: Its stored as number.
My class is structured as 
class Capacity {
total: number;
available: number;
}

Comment: And this is your problem, you forgot about %.
This should help: style="width:{{capacity.available}}%"

Comment: Tried with the percent gives me the same warning on the console..

**sanitizing unsafe style value width:54%**

Comment: Ok, try to replace it with angular way: [style.width]="capacity.available + '%'"

Comment: Btw. I reccomend to use native angular directive, the most popular one is probably: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap

Comment: Okay i will try them as well. Thank you so much with this though..
[style.width] worked just perfect for this one! 
If you post that as an answer then can marked it as a worked solution if anyone else is looking for the same.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Replace

```
style="width:{{capacity.available}}%"
```

with this (done in angular way)

```
[style.width]="capacity.available + '%'"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also set;

```
[ngStyle]="{width: capacity.available + '%'}"
```

Answer (score 4):

try with this for progress bar with label (value),

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{capacity.available}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{width: capacity.available + '%'}">
   {{capacity.available}}%
   </div>
</div>
```

Example,

```
capacity.available = 14
```

[image]